# Local variable count defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: java

I am trying to count the number of iterations using Java lambda expressions, but it's throwing a compile time error:

```
Local variable count defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
  names.add("Ajeet");
  names.add("Negan");
  names.add("Aditya");
  names.add("Steve");

  int count = 0;

  names.stream().forEach(s->
  {
    if(s.length()>6)
        count++;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The statement `count++;` is reassigning the variable `count`.

This is not allowed in a lambda expression. A local variable referenced in a lambda must be final (or effectively final, which means that it is not explicitly declared final, but would not break if `final` were added)

The alternative is to use an atomic integer:

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

names.stream().forEach(s -> {
    if (s.length() > 6)
        count.incrementAndGet();
});
```

***Note*** that using an atomic integer should be used only if you need to modify the local variable. If all this is just for computing the `count` variable, then the approach in EliotFrish's answer is much better.

Comment: Thank you for this example.  I had a use case where I wasn't simply counting something, but rather needed to pass an integer value from one iteration to the next, and AtomicInteger seems to fit the bill.

Comment: import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

Answer (score 8):

You can't access a non-`final` variable from an outer scope in a lambda. But you don't need to here, you can `filter` the `stream` based on your criteria and `count` that. Like,

```
long count = names.stream().filter(s -> s.length() > 6).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just here to provide a wider spectrum to overcome this error.

You can define your own consumer which counts:

```
class CountingConsumer implements Consumer<String>{
    int count;

    public void accept(String s){
        if(s.length() > 6){
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

And then pass an instance of this new class to the consumer:

```
CountingConsumer countingConsumer = new CountingConsumer();
names.forEach(countingConsumer);
```

Which finally lets you extract the count after the iteration:

```
System.out.println(countingConsumer.count);
```

But an even better answer is just to use a normal for loop:

```
int count = 0;
for(String s : names){
    if(s.length() > 6){
        count++;
    }
}
```